# cant generate the right soap response description with c#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, xsd

i've built a .net C# webservice.
one of my methods should return an XML with search resaults.

my current soap description im getting now when my method returns an XMLDocument Type is:

```
 SOAP 1.1
 The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

 POST /HARELCYBWS/HARELCYBWS.asmx HTTP/1.1
 Host: safemail-t.harel-ins.co.il
 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
 Content-Length: length
 SOAPAction: "http://www.securenet.co.il/GetSafeActivitiesXML"

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
     <GetSafeActivitiesXML xmlns="http://www.securenet.co.il">
       <safename>string</safename>
       <days>int</days>
       <FileName>string</FileName>
     </GetSafeActivitiesXML>
   </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
 Content-Length: length

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
     <GetSafeActivitiesXMLResponse xmlns="http://www.securenet.co.il">
       <GetSafeActivitiesXMLResult>xml</GetSafeActivitiesXMLResult>
     </GetSafeActivitiesXMLResponse>
   </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

I want the response to be like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
     <GetSafeActivitiesXMLResponse xmlns="http://www.securenet.co.il">
       <GetSafeActivitiesXMLResult>
 <results>
 <result>
       <safename>string</safename>
       <days>int</days>
       <username>string</username>
       <numberID>int</numberID>
       <comment>string</comment>
 </result>
 <result>
       <safename>string</safename>
       <days>int</days>
       <username>string</username>
       <numberID>int</numberID>
       <comment>string</comment>
 </result>
 <result>
       <safename>string</safename>
       <days>int</days>
       <username>string</username>
       <numberID>int</numberID>
       <comment>string</comment>
 </result>
 </results>
 </GetSafeActivitiesXMLResult>
     </GetSafeActivitiesXMLResponse>
   </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

i tried looking into schemas , serilization and all other stuff, and i dont really know what i'm doing there.
im new to xml, and i dont know all the details.

what can i do ? also, is XMLDocument is the right return type ?

please help,

thank you.

David

Comment: You have to perform all the queries before sending a response.  A XML file has only one root tag.<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap>
...
</soap>You can't just add a 2nd response after the first response.

Comment: yeah , i understood that , but what is the right workflow ?

Comment: Right workflow isn't to reinvent the wheel... Try [free](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3) version of [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/) to see if you like it. "Send/Receive" C# objects and work smart instead of fighting with protocols.

Comment: An html message should only have one body.  Should be like this : <soap:Body>
<soap:Envelope>
...
 </soap:Envelope>
<soap:Envelope>
...
 </soap:Envelope>
</soap:Body>

Comment: i really dont want to reinvent the wheel. my lack of knoledge with xml is my problem. i want the easiest solution, what is soap envelope? i will check the ServiceStack to see what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type is new class representing a list of the single result class.
worked for me.